# XNA 4.0 app closes suddenly when it hits a method without throwing any exceptions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, graphics, xna

As the title says, I have an XNA app that closes suddenly when it hits an app, but doesn't show any errors so I don't have a clue how to even begin to debug it. The code is very simple - I'm just playing with XNA and trying to render a simple triangle - so I can't imagine why it's stopping. The code that's running is

```
    VertexPositionColor[] vertices;

    public Terrain()
    {
        vertices = new VertexPositionColor[3];
        vertices[0].Position = new Vector3(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0f);
        vertices[0].Color = Color.Red;
        vertices[1].Position = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0f);
        vertices[1].Color = Color.Green;
        vertices[2].Position = new Vector3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0f);
        vertices[2].Color = Color.Yellow;
    }

    public void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(
            PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
            vertices,
            0,
            1,
            VertexPositionColor.VertexDeclaration);
    }
```

and it's the Draw() function that screws it up. When I remove the DrawUserPrimitives line it runs fine (although show nothing...)

Comment: btw, the screenmanager used is from this sample - [link](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) - and is just used to get the GraphicsDevice

Comment: It hit an app?  Anything owned by Apple?  Look in the Output window for first chance exceptions.  Play with Debug + Exceptions to catch them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that 'ScreenManager' is a class that inherits off 'DrawableGameComponent' and you are accessing the graphics device from there? Make sure somewhere in the constructor of your Game class you are initialising the GraphicsDeviceManager(this).

I think it's the 'GraphicsDevice' that your ScreenManager is grabbing statically that might not be initialised properly.

Comment: @Layoric I do set a GraphicsDeviceManager in my constructor, but I don't link it explicity with GraphicsDevice. The GraphicsDevice that I am accessing I passed to the ScreenManager from the Game class - do I need to do something to associate GraphicsDevice with the GraphicsDeviceManager?

Comment: @Jordan: Set a breakpoint on the `ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives` line.  When the application hits that breakpoint, check that the `GraphicsDevice` is instantiated and not `null`.

Comment: I'm not receiving any error, thats why I'm so confused. It just stops and kicks be back into the phones home screen

Comment: @Layoric: I think you meant to post that to Jordan and not me.

Comment: @Jordan, could you please put up the code from your game protected override void Initialize() just to double check what is being done. And also how you are parsing the graphicsdevice to your ScreenManager class? Also, in the code above are you using it like a property or a static call to GraphicsDevice from ScreenManager? Also to confirm, is this a Windows, Xbox or WP7 app? Apologies Neil.

Comment: Yeah sorry it is WP7, forgot to mention that. Anyway, I realised why it was failing, I guess I needed to specify an effect to use for rendering, so adding a `foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes) } pass.Apply(); /* Code snippet from above */ }` into the Draw method sorted it out. I still dont understand why it failed with no errors though